# Wild card search using Notepad

Tags: notepad++

In Notepad++ How can I search using wildcards for

```
get_GetTimeNow();
```

or

```
get_IsCurrent();
```

Then I want to replace it with

```
GetTimeNow
```

or

```
IsCurrent
```

In other words find

```
get_XXXX();
```

replace it with

```
XXXX;
```

I'm trying to do this with a large file

Answer (score 5):

Use Find. Pick the **Replace** Tab.

Set search Option to **Regex**. (Bottom Left).

Find What: `get_(.*)\(\);`

Replace With: `\1`

Note: This will only work if these tokens are on the end of the line. Not an unreasonable assumption if you have a `;` at the end.

**Explanation:**
`get_` matches the first 4 Characters.
`(.*)` matches the next any Characters. Also this saves the matched string.
`\(\);` matches the end of the string. Uses `\` to escape the `(`. `()` is what saves the matched string as used above. Because of this the match will not include this section.

Answer (score 3):

use regular expression :

```
get_([^\)]+)
```

replace by

```
\1
```

Answer (score 1):

Using Notepad++, my text looked like this:

```
(function() + "folder/" + "randomfilenameAB");
(function() + "folder/" + "randomfilenameBC");
(function() + "folder/" + "randomfilenameCD");
(function() + "folder/" + "randomfilenameDE");
```

and I needed it to look like:

```
(function() + "folder/randomfilenameAB" + string_var);
(function() + "folder/randomfilenameBC" + string_var);
(function() + "folder/randomfilenameCD" + string_var);
(function() + "folder/randomfilenameDE" + string_var);
```

This did the trick
Find what:
    `"folder/" \+ "(.*)"\);`

Replace with:
    `"folder/\1" \+ string_var\);`